# R strsplit doesn't split on "."?

Tags: r, strsplit

I am writing an R script and want to define a variable to be used in plot annotations as part of the file name. I thought I would use the strsplit() function. Here is my code and the output:

```
infile = "ACC_1346.table.txt"

x = strsplit(infile, ".")

class(infile)
[1] "character"

class(x)
[1] "list"

str(x)
List of 1
$ : chr [1:18] "" "" "" "" ...

x[[1]]
[1] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

I expected the final output to be:

```
[1] "ACC_1346" "table" "txt"
```

What is going on here?

Comment: '.' is a special character. split on '\\.' instead

Comment: `?strsplit` then look at the examples.  They recommend splitting on `[.]`.

Comment: `cat(example(strsplit, give.lines = TRUE)[16:21], sep = "\n")` is your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid regex altogether use `fixed = TRUE` in the call of `strsplit`

```
infile = "ACC_1346.table.txt"
x = strsplit(infile, ".", fixed = TRUE)

x

[[1]]
[1] "ACC_1346" "table" "txt"
```

Comment: Worth noting that this is also more efficient than doing `\\.`.

Answer (score 5):

`strsplit` seeks for a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to do it's splitting. In regex a ["."](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) is a wildcard that pretty much matches anything. To actually match the dot you need to escape using `\`. Since `\` is also an escape character in R, you need to escape it twice as `\\.`